# How do I change Dr Racket's Error Message Colours?

Tags: racket

I am using Dr Racket with a dark theme and the error message on the bottom is almost illegible. I couldn't find a setting in preferences to change this colour. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hmm....this seems to be an oversight on the part of DrRacket. Would you mind filing a bug report (at http://github.com/drracket/ ?)

Comment: I have opened an issue on their repo